# matplotlib Navigation Bar appears but has no functionality

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyside

Although I have gone through quite a few examples, none that I have seen appear to address the problem I am trying to solve.
I am using the Qt designer to create the GUI. I am also using PySide for Qt bindings and matplotlib for the Navigation bar.

Most of the examples I see are simple but they all use something similar to the following code which does not work for me since I am using Qt to generate the GUI.

```
    self.main_frame = QWidget()

    self.fig = Figure((5.0, 4.0), dpi=100)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
    self.canvas.setParent(self.main_frame)
    self.canvas.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
    self.canvas.setFocus()

    self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.main_frame)

    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)  # the matplotlib canvas
    vbox.addWidget(self.mpl_toolbar)
    self.main_frame.setLayout(vbox)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.main_frame)
```

So, I use the following code to successfully bring up a Navigation Bar in a frame I have created in my GUI. (navFrame)

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, tdsGui.Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
            # initialize the window
            self.ui = tdsGui.Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            # Navigation toolbar created in main
            self.fig = Figure((5, 5), dpi=100)
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
            self.canvas.setParent(self.ui.frame_plot) 

            self.canvas.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
            self.canvas.setFocus()
            # nav bar is successfully placed in nav frame
            self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, parent=self.ui.navFrame)
```

A separate frame holds the matplotlib image (frame_plot). I tried bringing up the Navigation bar in that frame but it also did not work.

The Navigation Bar appears but none of the buttons work are logically tied to my plot which is shown in the frame_plot (By the way, the plot uses animation, updating every 100ms. Could this have something to do with it?)

All suggestions welcome and I can provide more information as well

Thanks much

[image: Since I have had zero responses, I thought I would add an image to perhaps illustrate the problem I am having. I cannot get the Navigation buttons to work for the matplotlib plot. Do I need to write all the events for the Navigation buttons? I'm pretty new to Python (~2 months) I could use a few tips. Thanks]

Comment: Since I have had zero responses, I thought I would add an image to perhaps illustrate the problem I am having. I cannot get the Navigation buttons to work for the matplotlib plot. Do I need to write all the events for the Navigation buttons? I'm pretty new to Python (~2 months) I could use a few tips.

Comment: is your animation changing your axes limits?

Comment: #tcaswell, Thanks for your response. No the animation part is running perfectly.

Comment: Right, but if it is changing the axis limits, it would blow away the changes from the tool bar tools making them look non responsive

Comment: #tcaswell, If I understand your comment, you're thinking that if my axis limits change, this would affect the Navigation bar. The graph that is plotted has  ax1.set_ylim([-100, 100]), nothing is set for the xlim but when I did so nothing changed. The numbers being plotted are always 9999 data points from -100 to +100. But perhaps I misunderstood you as I do not completely understand your point.   But I think you're on to something, it must be due to the animation. Perhaps one cannot zoom a plot in real-time.